# Import error "This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 4.0 or newer"

Tags: android

I import this [project](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream) in android studio it occurs an error .

```
KotlinDslScriptsParameter(correlationId=179766420178900, scriptFiles=[]) => StandardKotlinDslScriptsModel(scripts=[], commonModel=CommonKotlinDslScriptModel(classPath=[], sourcePath=[], implicitImports=[]), dehydratedScriptModels={}) - took 0.002 secs

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 4.0 or newer.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Update the AS..

Comment: this is because of the project built on the new version of Android Studio 4.1(canary) which is in beta now. You cannot open using the current android studio. you have to install a canary version of the android studio from here https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Comment: I will check this project in  canary version.

Comment: yes, you can install both on a single machine.

Comment: It comes an error like this `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:countFirebaseDebugDexMethods'.
> Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.`